# Perl serialize UTF8 encoded data with JSON

Tags: json, perl, encoding, utf-8

I am a bit confused after reading the docs of JSON::XS. My question is: how can I encode/decode data, which are already in UTF8? calling encode_json seems to double encode them. I would like to create a JSON from a hash, which contains UTF8 encoded strings as well as decode JSON into a hash while keeping data UTF8 encoded. Is it possible, or do I need to mannually Encode::decode_utf8/encode_utf8 the data myself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are your strings UTF-8 encoded or do they just containt Unicode characters?

Comment: already UTF-8 encoded

Answer (score 1):

See [perldoc for Json::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.01/XS.pm#ENCODING/CODESET_FLAG_NOTES):

> **utf8 flag disabled**
>
> When utf8 is disabled (the default), then encode/decode generate and expect Unicode strings, that is, characters with high ordinal
>   Unicode values (> 255) will be encoded as such characters, and
>   likewise such characters are decoded as-is, no changes to them will be
>   done, except "(re-)interpreting" them as Unicode codepoints or Unicode
>   characters, respectively (to Perl, these are the same thing in strings
>   unless you do funny/weird/dumb stuff).
>
> This is useful when you want to do the encoding yourself (e.g. when you want to have UTF-16 encoded JSON texts) or when some other
>   layer does the encoding for you (for example, when printing to a
>   terminal using a filehandle that transparently encodes to UTF-8 you
>   certainly do NOT want to UTF-8 encode your data first and have Perl
>   encode it another time).
>
> **utf8 flag enabled**
>
> If the utf8-flag is enabled, encode/decode will encode all characters using the corresponding UTF-8 multi-byte sequence, and will
>   expect your input strings to be encoded as UTF-8, that is, no
>   "character" of the input string must have any value > 255, as UTF-8
>   does not allow that.
>
> The utf8 flag therefore switches between two modes: disabled means you will get a Unicode string in Perl, enabled means you get an UTF-8
>   encoded octet/binary string in Perl.